# How to fetch single record at a time in Kafka sink connector

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, apache-kafka-connect

I am using Kafka Sink Task to read records from Kafka topic.
The put() in SinkTask method is the entry point from where all records will be fetched.
Currently when the connector starts, it will fetch all records together which are not committed.
I want the worker task to fetch single record at a time.
How to do it?

```
class CustomSinkTask extends SinkTask{

    @Override
        public void put(Collection<SinkRecord> records) {

            System.out.println("Inside put method " );
            if(records != null)
                System.out.println("number of records fetched are:" + records.size());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try adding the following to the worker properties file

```
conusmer.max.poll.records=1
```

Answer (score 0):

You could achieve this by setting the max poll records to the desired number in the Kafka connect property file. Make sure you are prefixing the max.poll.records property with `consumer`. To know more about the worker properties, please refer to [this](https://docs.confluent.io/current/connect/userguide.html) page.

`consumer.max.poll.records=n`

Comment: as mentioned, i am using a Sink Task and not standalone consumer. The above property does not work for me